# Right way to test performance of Lambda expressions?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, anonymous-inner-class

I have used [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) to test the performance of Lambda against Anonymous Inner classes and below is how I did it:

```
public class LambdaVsAnonymousClass {

@Benchmark
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
public void testLambda() {
    // nonCapturing expressions
    NonCapturing nonCapturing = () -> System.out.println("ram");
    nonCapturing.test();
    // nonCapturing expressions
    NonCapturing nonCapturing2 = () -> System.out.println("bon");
    nonCapturing2.test();
}

@Benchmark
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
public void testAnonymousClass() {
    // anonymous classes
    NonCapturing nonCapturing = new NonCapturing() {
        @Override
        public void test() {
            System.out.println("ram");
        }
    };
    nonCapturing.test();
    // anonymous classes
    NonCapturing nonCapturing2 = new NonCapturing() {
        @Override
        public void test() {
            System.out.println("bon");
        }
    };
    nonCapturing2.test();
}

@Benchmark
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
public void testLambdaCapturing() {
    // lambda expressions
    final int i = 1;
    Capturing capturing = n -> System.out.println(n);
    capturing.test(i);
    // lambda expressions
    final int j = 2;
    Capturing capturing2 = n -> System.out.println(n);
    capturing2.test(j);
}

@Benchmark
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
public void testAnonymousClassCapturing() {
    // anonymous classes
    final int i = 1;
    Capturing capturing = new Capturing() {
        @Override
        public void test(int n) {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    };
    capturing.test(i);
    // anonymous classes
    final int j = 2;
    Capturing capturing2 = new Capturing() {
        @Override
        public void test(int n) {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    };
    capturing2.test(j);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
    Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
            .include(LambdaVsAnonymousClass.class.getSimpleName())
            .warmupIterations(5)
            .measurementIterations(5)
            .forks(1)
            .build();

    new Runner(opt).run();
}
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface NonCapturing {
    void test();
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface Capturing {
    void test(int n);
}
```

I was expecting Lambda to finish faster but I get the opposite result below. Am I incorrectly testing it? If yes, what's the correct way to actually test the faster performance of lambda expressions.

```
# Run complete. Total time: 00:00:42

Benchmark                                           Mode  Cnt   Score    Error  Units
LambdaVsAnonymousClass.testAnonymousClass           avgt    5  16.592 ±  4.084  us/op
LambdaVsAnonymousClass.testAnonymousClassCapturing  avgt    5  18.916 ±  4.469  us/op
LambdaVsAnonymousClass.testLambda                   avgt    5  18.618 ±  4.060  us/op
LambdaVsAnonymousClass.testLambdaCapturing          avgt    5  22.008 ± 16.729  us/op
```

> **NOTE:** The concept of capturing lambda expressions is incorrectly shown in the code. Read comments from @Holger for more understanding.

Comment: I'd try not to print to the console (`System.out.println()`) during benchmarks since the console/os would then have quite a huge impact on the performance and thus might warp the results.

Comment: Please have a look at [Oracle's performance test](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jvmls2013kuksen-2014088.pdf).

Comment: Unless you're enough of a performance expert to, say, _write_ JMH, my advice would be: stop worrying about nano-performance issues, and instead focus on writing clear code.  They're fast enough.

Comment: @BrianGoetz I am actually preparing this for a presentation in my college. But thanks very much for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be critical against benchmark results and also understand what you see. An error of `±4` is larger than the difference between the execution times of your “noncapturing” test execution times of `16.6` and `18.6`.
And it should definitely ring alarm bells when you see a result like `22` with an error of `±16.7`!

Additional, you have a wrong understanding of “capturing”. In your tests, there is no capturing lambda expression or anonymous class. You only have a function with zero parameters and a function with one parameter. This has nothing to do with capturing. The only difference is that in one case, you are printing an existing `String`, in the other, you are performing an `int` to `String` conversion. But even these differences are smaller than the reported error.

When considering the error, the results are within the same magnitude and, of course, the performance of printing code doesn’t depend on whether it resides in a  lambda expression or an anonymous inner class. It’s not clear why you expected the lambda expression to be faster. Lambda expressions are not magic.

Comment: I thought Lambdas to be faster as there's no need to create a separate class file and load the class etc as lambdas are converted to static methods and then there's also the optimisation by the lambda factory I guess if its a cold path. Please correct me.

Comment: And I didn't understand your statement, "there is no capturing lambda expression". I guess I am passing a `final` variable to the lambda which is outside the lambda expression. Can u pl correct me.

Comment: You are passing a **value** as an argument to the interface method. That value could also be a constant like `42` or an expression like `"bla".length()` or a mutable variable, it doesn’t matter. That doesn’t have anything to do with capturing. Capturing happens when your lambda expression itself references a variable from its outer context, not when it uses a parameter.

Comment: A lambda expression can have a faster cold start compared to loading a class, but that applies to the very first execution only, as classes are loaded exactly once. You are doing *five* warmup iterations before measuring another five executions. How do you expect to witness the difference of the very first execution here? Besides, when you benchmark methods containing only two lambda expressions, the cold start performance would be overshadowed by the initialization of the lambda meta factory anyway, as that class (and all classes used internally) have to be loaded too.

Comment: Your comments has clarified a lot of things @holger

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear *what exactly you are trying to test*. The creation and then an invocation? If so, then remove the System.out as they bite you pretty bad and then output should be measured in nano-seconds.

And the result in such a case (not surprisingly) is about the same:

```
LambdaVsClass.testAnonymousClass           avgt    5  0.335 ± 0.069  ns/op
LambdaVsClass.testAnonymousClassCapturing  avgt    5  0.337 ± 0.051  ns/op
LambdaVsClass.testLambda                   avgt    5  0.331 ± 0.051  ns/op 
LambdaVsClass.testLambdaCapturing          avgt    5  0.337 ± 0.043  ns/op
```

The results should differ if you would measure the SingleShotTime as the invokedynamic (without any warmup) bootstraps the lambda.